# Page Selection Dropdown with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/XhZqjw4x

I am helping to add a pagination feature to already existing code written by someone else. This code produces a page that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bmHv.jpg (used fictional character names for testing purposes).

**The Goal:** For the dropdown to show all of the available pages and when they click on a new page, it'll show the 25 accounts grabbed from the MySQL query for that particular page.

**What works:** I am able to dynamically create the dropdown to show the correct number of accounts per page and when I go to page 2 it does show the next set of accounts.

**The Problem:** Because of the $i counter I have starting on line 134, whenever anyone goes to a new page it'll automatically go to the last page because $i is obviously displaying the highest value. This also means that a user can't go back to a previous page.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<select name="accountPage" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
while ($i < $numPages) {
$i++;
$currentPage = $_POST['accountPage'];
    if ($i != $currentPage) {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'"';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected = "selected"';
    }
echo ">Page ".$i."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="accountPage" value="'.$i.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="masteremail" value="'.$masteremail.'">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

I have written and rewritten this code 3-4 different times in the last two months. It really should've been done ages ago but I keep hitting a roadblock and I can't figure out how to solve it (or my solutions lead me to hit another roadblock).

I am not interested in doing a "next page/previous page" because we have some people that have hundreds of accounts. It would just create frustration for the user so we (me and the one who coded the site) felt that a dropdown to select the new page would be easier.

I just need the user to be able to go to each page and also be able to go back to previous pages. We're completely stuck on how to fix this problem.
We considered potentially doing radio buttons for pages but that seems like it'll give us the same problems.

Can anyone give me some insight on how to solve this?

Comment: Your issue is probably caused by `echo '<input type="hidden" name="accountPage" value="'.$i.'">';` Since this is after your loop it will be the last value of `$i`. And since it is after your `<select>`, it will overwrite the selected value. Is there a reason you have this?

Comment: I know that that's the problem. I don't know how to fix it.

I have it because I need it to post the page number that they selected so the code around line 53 works properly and it displays the right data from the database.

At the time, that seemed like the best way to do it until it started screwing up. (Note: I have the full page of code in the pastebin at the top.)

Comment: Would it not be possible to just use a different name for the hidden input?

Comment: I've tried doing that but I still need it to grab what page that the user selects in order to enter that number into the MySQL query and show the next page of accounts. 

I can't figure out how to essentially just grab the option value for the page that they've selected.

I already know not to use $i for that hidden input so I need to add another variable in there but everything I end up adding either breaks the page or gives me the same problem.

Comment: If you're already passing the page they've chosen (hence, the page they will be on) using the select, why do you need the hidden input? I don't understand what the hidden input that in theory should be relaying the exact same information as the select is doing for you

Comment: That may be the issue actually. I was doing some research and the code I found had that I think so that's what made sense at the time. I don't work with forms a whole lot so there's a bit of a learning curve that may have prevented me from thinking about that.

Comment: Thank you @SGR! That fixed the whole thing!